# Area of square as a function of $\hat{a}$?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, area, quadrilateral

Suppose $ABCD $   is square ,and $AM=DN=QB=PC$   so $$A'B'C'D'$$
 is a square too.

Can someone help me to find area of $\bf{smaller -square}$(or $\color{red} {\Box A'B'C'D'}
$)  as a function of angle $\hat{a}$ .It seems to be easy ,but I get stuck on this problem.Thanks in advance.
[image]

Comment: Your diagram is a bit confusing. Your red line segments look like they are $AN$, $DP$, $CQ$, and $BM$ ... in this case, the square $MNPQ$ is not drawn in your diagram. Is this correct? Also, is $\hat{a}$ equal to $\angle DAN$?

Comment: @dxiv Angle $\hat{a}$ is $\angle DAN$ and not $\angle DMN$? ( [Damn, Daniel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Damn_Daniel) ? ) Is the red square the same as $MNPQ$? Are $M$, $N$, $P$, and $Q$ on the sides of the square? There is so much ambiguity here :(

Comment: It looks to me like the red square is *not* the same as $MNPQ$ ...

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee You are right, removed previous comment pending clarification.

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee, Soorry ,I edited it .

Comment: I need the area of smaller square .

Comment: @Khosrotash To be completely clear: there are three squares: $ABCD$, $MNPQ$, and the third (smallest) square which is bounded by your red line segments. You want to find the area of this third (smallest) square, right?

Comment: @ZubinMukerjee :Off course

Comment: @Khosrotash Side length of that square is $AN -AA'-D'N= AN - AM \cos a - DN \sin a\,$.

Comment: $\triangle ADD'$ is a right angled triangle. $A'D' = AD' - AA' = AD' - DD' = AD(\cos a - \sin a)$.

Comment: $S_{A'B'C'D'}=S_{ABCD}-4S_{ADD'}$.

Comment: I just labelled the points $A$ through $L$, I found that easier to manage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

Let $\alpha=\angle NAD$, $a=|AB|$. Then

\begin{align}
S_{A'B'C'D'}&=S_{ABCD}-4S_{ADD'}
\\
&=
a^2-4\,\tfrac12 a\,a\,\cos\alpha\sin\alpha
\\
&=a^2(1-\sin2\alpha)
.
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Label the points $A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H, I, J, K, L$ as in this diagram:

[image]

Now, let $AD = x$ and let $\angle DAF = \alpha$.

We wish to express the area of square $IJKL$ in terms of $x$ and $\alpha$.

---

First, let $DF = AE = y$. The tangent of $\alpha$ can then be written

$$\tan \alpha = \frac{y}{x} \,\,\implies\,\, y = x\tan\alpha$$

Triangle $ADF$ is right, so we can apply the Pythagorean theorem to find that $$AF = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$

To find $IL$, we will find $AI$ and $LF$ and subtract both from $AF$.

---

To find $AI$, note that triangles $AIE$ and $ADF$ are similar. This means that

$$\frac{AE}{AI} = \frac{AF}{AD}$$

$$\frac{y}{AI}=\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{x}$$

$$AI = \frac{xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$

---

To find $LF$, note that triangles $DLF$ and $ADF$ are similar. This means that

$$\frac{DF}{LF} = \frac{AF}{DF}$$

$$\frac{y}{LF} = \frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}{y}$$

$$LF = \frac{y^2}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$

---

Finally we can find $IL$:

$$IL = AF - AI - LF$$

$$IL = \sqrt{x^2+y^2} - \frac{y^2+xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$

This means that our final answer for the area of square $IJKL$ is:

$$(IL)^2 = \boxed{\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2} - \frac{y^2+xy}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\right)^2\,}$$

where $x = AF$ and $y = x\tan \alpha$, with $\alpha = \angle DAF$.